# how to fill another income or savings section in UK visa application

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

After filling income details there a question "Do you have another income or any savings?"- I have a savings account which has all my savings from my salary and mostly from bonuses, both are recorded in my paychecks, so should I say that I have savings or is it something related to other deposit and stocks?

Comment: You use your bonus for savings. Others use it to buy presents for their kids and wife. Some spend the money on a short trip the month after, or buy a new car, or pay off a loan, or..... Just because "they are recorded in your paycheck" doesn't mean that money is still available for your trip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to savings of whatever nature. If you have savings, state ‘yes’ and provide the relevant evidence.